# bcrypt.compare returning false everytime

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, hash, bcrypt

I am creating a simple signup and sign in route whose functions are as follows:

```
const createUser = async (username, email, password) => {
    try {
        const existingUsername = await User.findOne({ username });
        const existingEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUsername)
            throw new Error(
                'Username already taken. Please choose a different username.'
            );

        if (existingEmail)
            throw new Error(
                'User already exists. Please sign in instead of signing up.'
            );

        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);

        const user = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
        await user.save();

        const token = createToken(user);

        return { user, token };
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};

// login a user
const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username });

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error('User not found. Please sign up first.');
        }

        const passwordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
        console.log({ passwordMatch });
        if (!passwordMatch) {
            throw new Error('Invalid password. Please try again.');
        }

        const token = createToken(user);

        return { user, token };
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

**EDIT** this is how i am calling them in routes file

```
router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body;
        const { user, token } = await createUser(username, email, password);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'User registered successfully',
            token,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});

router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;

        const { user, token } = await loginUser(username, password);

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', token });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});
```

when I do `console.log()` the values of password, it gives me the plain text that I am passing for login, the password I used while signing up and when I console the user.password field, it gives me the hashed value from the database.
but somehow the compare function is returning false always, idk why please help me. I have tried finding ways on net and other similar questions but none is working.
**EDIT** this is my models/Users.js file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },      },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: "users",
  }
);

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: How are you calling `loginUser`? What are the values? Is the password filled in? Does `user` have a password set?

Comment: yes, i am calling through routes, i have edited the question to see how i am calling these functions in routes handling

Comment: Can you add all  the code for User model? (not just schema)

Comment: i edited my question to show the model file of users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hashing the password both in pre save hook and in the router. If you remove one of them, it should work.

```
        const user = new User({ username, email, password });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to comment due to low reputation.
I have been face this issue long ago and the solution of this issue is you have to interchange the parameter of calling function and you will definitely get rid of this problem.